# Why is the difference of datetime = zero in the following dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This  issue that  I am facing is very simple yet weird and has troubled me to no end.

I have a dataframe as follows :

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_convert('US/Pacific')
df.head()

        vehicle_id  trip_id                                 datetime    
6760612 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:00-08:00       
6760613 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:01-08:00    
6760614 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:02-08:00      
6760615 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:03-08:00       
6760616 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:04-08:00
```

I am trying to find out the datatime difference as follows ( in two different ways) :

```
df['datetime_diff'] = df['datetime'].diff()

df['time_diff'] = (df['datetime'] - df['datetime'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

For a particular trip_id, I have the results as follows :

```
df[trip_frame['trip_id'] == '4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716'][['datetime','datetime_diff','time_diff']].head()

                   datetime         datetime_diff   time_diff
6760612 2017-01-01 10:00:00-08:00   NaT             NaN
6760613 2017-01-01 10:00:01-08:00   00:00:01        1.0
6760614 2017-01-01 10:00:02-08:00   00:00:01        1.0
6760615 2017-01-01 10:00:03-08:00   00:00:01        1.0
6760616 2017-01-01 10:00:04-08:00   00:00:01        1.0
```

But for some other trip_ids like the below, you can observe that I am having the datetime difference as zero (for both the columns) when it is actually not.There is a time difference in seconds.

```
df[trip_frame['trip_id'] == '01b8a24510cd4e4684d67b96369286e0'][['datetime','datetime_diff','time_diff']].head(4)

         datetime            datetime_diff  time_diff
3236107 2017-01-28 03:00:00-08:00   0 days  0.0
3236108 2017-01-28 03:00:01-08:00   0 days  0.0
3236109 2017-01-28 03:00:02-08:00   0 days  0.0
3236110 2017-01-28 03:00:03-08:00   0 days  0.0

df[df['trip_id'] == '01c2a70c25e5428bb33811ca5eb19270'][['datetime','datetime_diff','time_diff']].head(4)

        datetime             datetime_diff  time_diff
8915474 2017-01-21 10:00:00-08:00   0 days  0.0
8915475 2017-01-21 10:00:01-08:00   0 days  0.0
8915476 2017-01-21 10:00:02-08:00   0 days  0.0
8915477 2017-01-21 10:00:03-08:00   0 days  0.0
```

Any leads as to what the actual issue is ? I will be very grateful.

Update - I tried out @n1k31t4's approach and got the following results for those problematic rows. Did not even do the time-zone conversion. It is still so weird and surprising.

```
                        datetime    timestamps    timestamp_diffs    date_diffs
3236107 2017-01-28 11:00:00+00:00   1485601200000000    0.0          0 days
3236108 2017-01-28 11:00:01+00:00   1485601201000000    0.0          0 days
3236109 2017-01-28 11:00:02+00:00   1485601202000000    0.0          0 days
3236110 2017-01-28 11:00:03+00:00   1485601203000000    0.0          0 days
3236111 2017-01-28 11:00:04+00:00   1485601204000000    0.0          0 days
```

Comment: Quite possibly, the error is in your assignment of the `seconds` to the dates in the later filters. Do a quick inspection of those values before the calculation / assignment, what do they yield?

Comment: Additionally, pandas' `groupby` function might be helpful here for assigning days. Of which, values can be set using `df.loc[]`

Comment: The values are 0 nevertheless, both before converting into seconds and after converting into seconds. I am trying to find out the difference between the datatimes for a row as compared against the previous row. It works fine for certain rows but for other rows, it goes haywire. It's behaving the same for both the methods.

Comment: How should one understand this format: `2017-01-01 10:00:00-08:00` ? January 1st 2017, 10hr 0min 0sec, but then what does `-08:00` mean exactly?

Comment: `-08:00` indicates 8hours 'back' from GMT. It is for Pacific Standard Time.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to see where the problem is with your code; given your comments, my guess is a problem in the timezone conversion.

I cannot see a problem exactly, buy my suggestion to help debug your situation would be to convert all time to *timestamps* - by default that will be seconds since the epoch (January 1st 1970). These are then simply normal `float64` values (I convert to integer microseconds below). If your differences are still returning zero, subtracting simple number, then the problem cannot be in the differences.

Here is a minimal working example. A simple dateframe with timestamps with millisecond frequency:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=datetime(2016,1,1,0,0,1), 
    ...:     end=datetime(2016,1,1,0,0,2), freq='ms'), columns=["dates"]).head(10)    # just take first 10 rows for simplicity
```

Make a new column, converting the dates into microseconds since the epoch, as an integer:

```
In [2]: df["timestamps"] = df.dates.apply(lambda x: int(datetime.timestamp(x) * 1e6))                              

In [3]: df                                                                                                         
Out[3]: 
                    dates        timestamps
0 2016-01-01 00:00:01.000  1451602801000000
1 2016-01-01 00:00:01.001  1451602801001000
2 2016-01-01 00:00:01.002  1451602801002000
3 2016-01-01 00:00:01.003  1451602801003000
4 2016-01-01 00:00:01.004  1451602801004000
5 2016-01-01 00:00:01.005  1451602801005000
6 2016-01-01 00:00:01.006  1451602801006000
7 2016-01-01 00:00:01.007  1451602801007000
8 2016-01-01 00:00:01.008  1451602801008000
9 2016-01-01 00:00:01.009  1451602801009000
```

You could at this point check that there are no duplicates in any of your columns, using:

```
In [4]: df.T.duplicated()                                                                                          
Out[4]: 
dates         False
timestamps    False
dtype: bool
```

If there are duplicates, that could be the cause of differences equal to zero.

Now compute the differences, in my case all 1-millisecond differences (1000 microseconds):

```
In [5]: df[["date_diffs", "timestamp_diffs"]] = df.diff(1)                                                        

In [6]: df                                                                                                        
Out[6]: 
                    dates        timestamps      date_diffs  timestamp_diffs
0 2016-01-01 00:00:01.000  1451602801000000             NaT              NaN
1 2016-01-01 00:00:01.001  1451602801001000 00:00:00.001000           1000.0
2 2016-01-01 00:00:01.002  1451602801002000 00:00:00.001000           1000.0
3 2016-01-01 00:00:01.003  1451602801003000 00:00:00.001000           1000.0
4 2016-01-01 00:00:01.004  1451602801004000 00:00:00.001000           1000.0
5 2016-01-01 00:00:01.005  1451602801005000 00:00:00.001000           1000.0
6 2016-01-01 00:00:01.006  1451602801006000 00:00:00.001000           1000.0
7 2016-01-01 00:00:01.007  1451602801007000 00:00:00.001000           1000.0
8 2016-01-01 00:00:01.008  1451602801008000 00:00:00.001000           1000.0
9 2016-01-01 00:00:01.009  1451602801009000 00:00:00.001000           1000.0
```

Add a sample zero difference and retrieve the index of zero differences:

```
In [7]: df.iloc[3, 3] = 0.0                                                                                       

In [8]: np.where(df == 0)                                                                                         
Out[8]: (array([3]), array([3]))
```

Hopefully that will be enough to find where there could actually be zero difference. If all of that works out without zero differences, I would either look into your timezone conversion (maybe they do some rounding there?) or report a bug to [**the pandas issues**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

---

### EDIT

After your update trying my debugging method, and seeing this:

[image: difference between non-unique integers is never zero]

I believe there must be either a bug or an inherent limitation to your system.

#### Pandas Bug

A bug might be in your specific version of Pandas and its `df.diff()` method. Check your version of Pandas with `pd.__version__` and look on the issues page I linked above for any clues ... maybe just try the latest stable version anyway.

#### 32-bit system

Another possible solution would be that you are running on a 32-bit system and so could actually lose the precision required for my example above.
A 32-bit integer can only retain precision for 10 digits. My timestamps above require 12 digits. You can find out on like this, on [Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-find-if-processor-is-64-bit-or-not/) or [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/827218/how-to-determine-whether-a-computer-is-running-a-32-bit-version-or-64) or [Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12666/how-to-check-whether-my-intel-based-mac-is-32-bit-or-64-bit).

Additionally, you could retry my example, but only look at *seconds* instead of *microseconds*, just to be sure.

Comment: I tried your approach and have updated the results in my question. It is still so weird.

Comment: @dravid07 - Please see my edit.